# cfinvoke execution order

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, cfinvoke

I have a cfinvoke which writes to a table like 200,000 records.
Then I have a another cfinvoke writes about the 100,000 records to the **same** table.

I'm wondering how will this be executed?

- Would cfinvoke execute first then once done, execute cfinvoke 2? 
  OR
- would cfinvoke 1 and 2 execute simultaneously in the background, continue with the rest of the page, even before either one of the executions are done?

P.S, cfinvoke 2 is **NOT** depended of cfinvoke 1, but I prefer them to execute one after another.

Any suggestions of making option 2 happen is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 2 `<cfinvoke>`'s are invoked in the same request, back-to-back, without use `<cfthread>` then "cfinvoke execute first then once done, execute cfinvoke 2"

however, if you click refresh before the request is completed, and you're not using any sort of `<cflock>`, the records from 2nd request might intermingled with your 1st request.

Comment: I can make sure request won't get refreshed, but good to know about <cflock> for future reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

A ColdFusion template runs in a single-threaded and synchronous manner. Statements execute one after another, each statement takes as long as it needs. `<cfinvoke>` is no exception.